# Durandal Open Modal Dialog if specific route was triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, durandal

I like to open a modal dialog if the page was rerouted during an auth error (usually thats rerouted to /account/Login).

I have a Durandal modal dialog which I like to trigger if the user hits /#/Login somehow.

Comment: `#/Login` sounds more like a kind of 404 page. Why don't you put the html fragment that's in the modal dialog into `login.html` directly?

Comment: I just did that more or less.